# Altium: polygon pour with a fully included round hole

Tags: altium, copper-pour

I need to draw a round hole on a polygon pour.

I've followed this [documentation](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-PolygonPour((Polygon+Pour))_AD) (see video in 
"Subtracting Selected Polygon Pours" paragraph). It explains that you must first selected the reference polygon and then all the polygons you want to "remove" from the reference polygon.

My concern is that I can't select the other polygons while they are fully inside the reference polygon. If I click using the shift key. It deselect the reference polygon...

How to do that?

**Edit:**
I need to remove the highlighted circle from the disk but not the other
copper region:

Starting from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Comment: One way would be through the polygon manager I guess?

Comment: What Altium version? I think they have mucked up the interface to select one of an overlapping set of objects in the most recent versions.

Comment: version  16.0.5 .

Comment: Draw a circle using primitives on whatever layer you want, then select the circle and go to Tools -> Convert -> Create Cutout from Selected Primitives

Comment: *Then just delete the original primitives

Comment: How about placing a full circle, using an arc track, and setting its property to 'keep-out'?  Re-pour the polygon with "remove islands" or "remove unconnected copper" enabled.  Keep-out tracks are not exported to Gerber.

Comment: @DerStrom8: It removes copper from all polygons. I need to remove copper for a specific polygon. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/dsjK0G])

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen: I did the keep out [screenshot](https://ibb.co/i1Lnnw) but repouring with remove island or remove dead copper removes everything [screenshot with dialog and result in the background](https://ibb.co/gBAWEb).

Comment: @Julien No it doesn't, it only creates a cutout in the polygon on the current layer. I just tested that. I have Altium 17 though, maybe they changed it for this version? Doubt it though.

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift and left click on all the polygons, then let go of shift and right click on the poly you want the others to subtract from. The right click should give you a list where you can select (with left click) the subtract command.

Comment: I can't see the menu, you're talking about.... [screenshot](https://ibb.co/ferpXw)

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I did:

Convert center circle to polygon pour, put it in the right position in polygon manager, repour, convert big disk to free primitive, delete center disk.
This must be done when everything is done because, repouring cannot be done anymore on the big disk.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a circle?

Is this clearing the pad in the center?  If so, how about a clearance rule between named polygon and named pad (or maybe put them in a pad class if you have many to do).

If you add a dummy pad (or other distinctly queryable object) in the middle, with a round shape, this should even do the same (circular) outline.  Or, say the middle pad is constructed from a round pad (for connectivity) plus a Region tagged for soldermask and paste (i.e., the older way to make custom pad outlines), then you'll already have that central pad to reference by rule, while keeping the desired shape.